# Drag and drop to a TableLayout

Tags: android

I have

```
<TableLayout
  android:id="@+id/top_container"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:columnCount="10"
  android:rowCount="10"
   ... etc ...
```

When I drag an ImageView to the TableLayout it positions itself on the first free cell. Is it possible to drop the image to any cell in the layout?

Regards
Peter

Comment: This is not TableLayout related but worth to check https://github.com/theredsunrise/AndroidCoolDragAndDropGridView

Comment: Thanks but that solution does the same thing, it sorts the item when dropping. I want it to remain in the dropped position.
Note: Any layout that allows the dropped item to remain in the dropped position will do.